# $f(z)$ be an even entire, then $f(\sqrt z) $ obey the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$  be an even entire function, assume that $f'(z)$ is also entire,  show that $g(z)=f(\sqrt z) $  obey the Cauchy-Riemann equations in the complex plane,  and $g_x(z)=-ig_y(z)=\dfrac{f^\prime(\sqrt z) }{2\sqrt z}$ if $z\ne0$, and $g_x(0)=-ig_y(0)=\dfrac{f''(0)}{2}$

here, $\sqrt z$ use nonpositive real axis $(-\infty, 0]$ as a branch cut; $g_x(z)=u_x(z)+iv_x(z),g_y(z)=u_y(z)+iv_y(z)$

Only the limits and continuity of functions, the Cauchy-Riemann equations can be allowed, the complex integration and Taylor series are forbidden

---

I think, as the problem [Complex valued function   $\cos\sqrt z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184554/complex-valued-function-cos-sqrt-z), if  we permit the power series, the work will be easy

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(2n)}(0) z^{2n}}{(2n)!},  $$

then, $f(\sqrt z) $ is entire.

But, with the definition of analytic ,  the Cauchy-Riemann equations and $\sqrt z$ is continuous in $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$, I cannot solve the problem.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: you need the theorem that holomorphic $\implies$ analytic, hence it always reduces to the power series, I don't see how you'll do without

Comment: Compare http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513230/show-that-if-fz-is-a-continuous-function-on-a-domain-d-such-that-fzn. Your's is the special case $N=2$.

Comment: @MartinR  $f(\sqrt z)$ not $ \sqrt{f(z)}$.  Thanks

Comment: You are right, my fault.